# Problems with Second monitor with persistent usb of elmentary OS 5.1 hera

Tags: release-hera

I have a persistent USB running with elemntary OS 5.1 hera, and have been struggling with trying to connect a second monitor to my laptop, Ive got it to the point where it shows the wallpaper on the second monitor and has the mouse moving but I cant get any windows open on it or drag any windows to it.